# SHould i ignore ajax,css,call in jmeter load testing

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am new to jmeter load testing. i am using jmeter test script recorder to record and run the load testing and jmeter capture all type of calls including css,ajax etc.While doing load testing should i ignore css,ajax or i have to include them as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well-behaved JMeter test assumes that each JMeter thread (virtual user) replicates real user with all its stuff including

- CSS, JavaScript, fonts, images, etc. downloading
- [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [think times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time) between operations
- etc.

So you:

1. Should not be recording these calls as if you record them - JMeter will execute the calls sequentially
2. Instead you need to [configure JMeter to download](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) these CSS, images, etc. using parallel pool of 6 threads (this is what real browsers do). The same applies to AJAX calls, they're being executed by the same pool of 6 parallel threads. Also remember that JMeter cannot execute client-side JavaScript so you will have to take care of simulating AJAX requests yourself using i.e. [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)

Comment: Thak you so much for sharing the details..Documents which you shared clarified lot of other queries as well :)